# What kind of operation/rule was applied here?

Tags: exponentiation

Maybe this is a typo in our assignment and solution, but I can't tell.

The question:

[image]

The solution:

[image]

What happened here with the minus signs in the first factor and in the exponent?

**Edit**: the assignment asked for the fourier transform of $f(x)$. So I guess the expression highlighted in yellow is supposed to be equivalent to $f(x)$

Comment: All there is is some equation with no meaning whatsoever given to the symbols. Where is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand, what the question is.

Note however, that $|a-b| = |b-a|$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

The minus changing to a plus seems to be a typo though (provided the yellow colored expression is supposed to be the same as $f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Ok, i'm going to assume it's a typo. That absolute rule already helped me a lot, thanks!